# Change 8 digit value in to a European date format

Tags: php, date

Using PHP I have data feed fed in to an array: `$index->indexDate` this gives me a European style 8 digit date (There is no time just the 8 digit date).

For example: The value `28112012` should result in `28-11-2012` or `28/12/2012`. I have tried several methods but I am not sure how I should be doing this, I keep ending up with a 1970 date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `substring` ? [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$date="28112012";
$new_date=substr($date,0,2)."-".substr($date,2,2)."-".substr($date,4,4);
```

Use `-` or `/` .

Answer (score 5):

There's the DateTime class, and its `format` methods

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '28112012')->format('d-m-Y')
```

If your application need to handle full internationalization ("i18n"), then you should take a look at [PHP's Intl extension](http://php.net/manual/fr/intl.examples.basic.php). Basically, it adapt the formatting of numbers, date, currency, etc. for every country.